# FFMPEG copy audio from input to output

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using the below ffmpeg code to embed a video over a background image

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i <INPUT BACKGROUND IMAGE> -i <INPUT VIDEO FILE> -
filter_complex "[1]scale=515:386 [vid]; [0][vid]overlay=43:46:shortest=1[out]" 
-map "[out]" -y <OUTPUT VIDEO FILE>
```

This will put my input video file on top of my input background image and create a final output video file. However, I need the audio from the input video file to be copied over to the output video file as well. How do I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the audio as well and set codec mode for it to `copy`.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i <INPUT BACKGROUND IMAGE> -i <INPUT VIDEO FILE> 
 -filter_complex "[1]scale=515:386 [vid]; [0][vid]overlay=43:46:shortest=1[out]" 
 -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:a copy -y <OUTPUT VIDEO FILE>
```